# Excel xlsx file modified into a dataframe is not recognized by an R package that uses dataframe

Tags: dataframe

I uploaded an Excel xlsx file then created a dataframe by converting numeric variables into categories.  When I run a R package that uses dataframe, the output shows the following error:

```
> library(DiallelAnalysisR)
> Griffing(Yield, Rep, Cross1, Cross2, GriffingData41, 4, 1)
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "Trt", value = character(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 20
```

When I issue a str() function, it shows the modifications of the numeric columns into catergories as below.

```
> str(GriffingData41)
'data.frame':   20 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ CROSS1: Factor w/ 4 levels "1","2","3","4": 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 4 ...
 $ CROSS2: Factor w/ 4 levels "2","3","4","5": 1 2 3 4 2 3 4 3 4 4 ...
 $ REP   : Factor w/ 2 levels "1","2": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 ...
 $ YIELD : num  11.9 14.5 9 13.5 20.5 9.8 16.5 22.1 18.4 19.4 ...
```

Is this a problem in my dataframe creation?

I would appreciate it if I could be helped with this error.  By the way, I am running this in R Studio.

Thank you.

Note: This is not really a solution to my problem but I managed to move forward by saving my Excel data in CSV format; changing the data type of the specific columns to character and importing to R Studio.  From there, creating the dataframe and running the R package went smoothly.  Still, I am curious why it did not work on the "xlsx" file.